# How do attack rolls and criticals affect a 2d6 vs 1d12 damage roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, dice, statistics

For example, given the probability distribution between two similar weapons:

---

D&D 5E Weapons - Basic Rules pg.48:

[image: Text]

---

Damage Discrete Distribution - [AnyDice](https://anydice.com/):

[image: Text2]

---

Its evident that Greatsword is more reliable and has a higher mean damage roll.

But how does this change if we factor in an attack roll with some chance to hit? Do critical hits make the Greataxe preferential?

Comment: Do you want to factor in chances to hit as well? Something like "If I have a 15% chance to hit (5% of which is the crit) which weapon should I use?"

Comment: Yes, I leave it up to you to choose.

Comment: Very related: "[Is Greatsword superior to Greataxe?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120604)"

Comment: @Medix2 that answer is great, and addresses the critical hit portion of this one. Thanks for linking it!

Comment: @Medix2 Yes it does.

Comment: Also related: [How do you calculate average damage for DPR comparisons?(https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138209/how-do-you-calculate-average-damage-for-dpr-comparisons)